# Why is clang recompiling all C++ files including a header file if the recent change does not impact most of them?

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation, clang, compiler-optimization

I have a **Constants** header file that is included by most of my source files. If I change a constant in there that is only used by ~2 source files, then Clang is still recompiling all ~300 source files that include this header file.

Is there any way to only recompile the source files that get actually influenced by the change I made without having to split the Constants file into many tiny parts?
I would really like to speed up the compilation process after small changes.

Since my build system and environment seems to matter: I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 on OSX, compiling C++ code for iOS.

Comment: Clang compiles what you tell it to compile. What are you using to command it? Make? Something else?

Comment: You can split the header in multiple files and include only the parts needed in each source.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Clang or the compiler in general, but with your *build system*. And if you have around 300 files which depends on the header file you modify, how would the build system know that only two are affected by the change you made? Perhaps you should think about the build system and the dependencies and your design, so that no single file will affect so many different other files. Perhaps split up the header file into smaller pieces?

Comment: Another hint: Precompiled headers.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I edited the question with some info about my build system: Xcode 8.3.3 on OSX, building for iOS.

Comment: @arrowd Will precompiled headers really help here? Do changes to precompiled headers not also force a full recompile?

Comment: I could not find any information about how xcode handles file dependencies, but usually it is impossible to find out what code is actually affected by a change to an included header without recompiling. Build systems like make or ninja rely on modified timestamps for this, anything else would be too slow. If you want to speed up compilation, split up the constants header by topic and only include the parts where needed.